# Flutter Image to list of int

Tags: flutter, dart, image-processing

I have this python code that read image from path and generate json file of image data

```
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
resized_image = cv2.resize(
    image,
    (416, 416)
)
image = np.ascontiguousarray(resized_image, dtype=np.float32)
flattened_image = image.flatten().astype(int).tolist()
json_data = {"pixels": flattened_image}
print(json_data)
```

the output of this python code is something like this :

```
{'pixels': [203, 203, 203, 202, 202, 202, 201, 201, 201, 202, .... 92, 92]}
```

now I want to generate the same json in ***flutter*** for the same image input

```
final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(image_path);
final image = img.decodeImage(bytes.buffer.asUint8List());
final resized_image = img.copyResize(image!, width: 416, height: 416);
??
??
json_data = {"pixels":  ???? }
```

**Question**

how I can generate the exact json content starting from `resized_image` object or image path ? what is the equivalent of `np.ascontiguousarray(resized_image, dtype=np.float32)` and `image.flatten().astype` in flutter to have the same output as python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have try List.from(img.Image.fromBytes(width: 416, height: 416, bytes: imageInput.buffer)) --> not working , I have try this https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/blob/ce8075a391e02e0cc0bc6c2db950aa961a17d745/example/lib/main.dart#L145C4-L145C4 --> not working, and. lot of other method but not able to have same result